# registry keys are getting imported under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\WOW6432Node\ on windows server2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-registry, operating-system

I am trying to import registry keys along with my application installation using powershell. I am using below command to import registry values (which is placed in a file RegFileName)

reg import ".\$RegFileName" /reg:32

My expectation is that these registry values should get imported at below path :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\

But it is getting imported at below path :
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\WOW6432Node\

Above behavior is happening for windows server 2016 operating system, whereas on windows server 2008R2 and windows server 2012 OS it is importing to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\" which is expected for application.

But on windows server 2016 OS, there is another WOW6432Node node present under WOW6432Node.

How I can modify my powershell so that it will import registry settings at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\" instead of "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\WOW6432Node\" on windows server 2016 OS.

Comment: Looks like on 2016 the last part is added by default. Why not remove it from your import path ?

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. It worked for me.

Comment: You shouldn't ever be specifying `WOW6432Node` as part of a registry path.  Use `/reg:32` if you need to import into the 32-bit registry.